# Edit text loosing focus after typing something

Tags: android, adapter, expandablelistview

I am inflating edit text in adapter class within of a list view. View is looking cool multiple edit text are appearing properly but when I do focus on the edit text or if I try to type something it loosing focus I tried to adding listeners, changing manifest file but nothing works for me.

following code is not working for me

```
@Override
 public View getChildView(int position, int i1, boolean b, View view, 
 ViewGroup viewGroup) {
 EditText comment = view.findViewById(R.id.txtRecordComment);

 comment.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (lastFocussedPosition == -1 || lastFocussedPosition == position) {
                        lastFocussedPosition = position;
                        edittext.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            }, 200);

        } else {
            lastFocussedPosition = -1;
        }
    }
});

   return view;
}
```

please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: You even don't need of this **comment.setOnFocusChangeListener**. Just comment out and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a `ListView`, it is bound to happen with your current code implementation.

You must remember that if your `EditText` is in a ListView, every key down will result in the edit text losing and getting focus because all the views are redrawn, so the edit text representing whatever row used to be focused is now a completely different object.

To get the expected behaviour, declare a variable in your adapter: `int focusedRow`. In `getView` method of your adapter, add an onFocusChanged listener to the EditText and when that edit text gains focus, set focusedRow = whatever row the focused EditText happens to be in.

Also set any edit text that is in the currentlyFocusedRow to be focused.

**Update**:

If you have multiple `EditText`s, add an onFocusChanged listener to each edit text.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in Android Manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Hope this will work